# Is there a list of what groovy commands are sandboxed in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm working on some jenkins pipeline scripted code and keep hitting things that are sandboxed, or at least I think they're sandboxed.

I'm trying to track down a list of what is sandboxed in the Jenkins / Groovy playground.  So far my searches aren't finding anything useful.

Does anyone know where I can find a list of what stuff would require an admin approval to run?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whitelisting/blacklisting is part of the [*Script Security Plugin*](https://plugins.jenkins.io/script-security). There are extension points that allow other plugins to build and customize the script whitelist, as well. The general built-in signatures can be seen in these files:

- [`src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/sandbox/whitelists/blacklist`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/script-security-plugin/blob/4fc47a35e7c0356e0994869040f976abe20c7ae4/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/sandbox/whitelists/blacklist#L1)
- [`src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/sandbox/whitelists/generic-whitelist`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/script-security-plugin/blob/4fc47a35e7c0356e0994869040f976abe20c7ae4/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/sandbox/whitelists/generic-whitelist)
- [`src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/sandbox/whitelists/jenkins-whitelist`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/script-security-plugin/blob/4fc47a35e7c0356e0994869040f976abe20c7ae4/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/sandbox/whitelists/jenkins-whitelist)